# Hold Poco Model (Domain Model) in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

is there any way to hold Domain Model's data in Session?
in ASP.NET MVC3 c#

Comment: [What did you try](http://whatdidyoutry.com)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just place in Session[]

```
MyModel mm;

Session["MyModel"] = mm; 
MyModel mm = (MyModel)Session["MyModel"];
```

This works for Entity Framework loaded objects too (you can place the proxies in session), though you cannot do things with them that require a context after the context they were loaded through has been disposed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var domainModelData = GetDomainModelData();

Session["DomainModelData"] = domainModelData;
```